# C++ Interaction between constexpr and std::is_contant_evaluated

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

In a CppNow talk (Don't constexpr All the Things - David Sankel), it used the following function as an example:

```
constexpr int f()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
       // slow version at runtime but that can be evaluated at compile-time
    } else {
       // fast version at runtime
    }
}
```

and David said that in this example, the definition of the function depends on `std::is_constant_evaluated()`, and so the function will be always "slow" at runtime or always "fast" at runtime.

But at the same time, `std::is_constant_evaluated()` is `true` or `false` depending on the context of the usage, right? For example:

```
const int i = f();
```

In this example, the compile will try to calculate the value of the constant `i` at compile-time. For that, the compiler calls `f` with `is_constant_evaluated` set to `true` to see what happens. If it can evaluate at compile-time the result, it does it and sets the final value of `i` at compile-time.

However, from other contexts, `f()` could be called with `std::is_constant_evaluated` set to `false`.

So, if `std::is_constant_evaluated` is set to `true` or `false` depending on the "caller context", and thus both possibilities happens at different points in code, how can the "callee" have only one definition?

Sorry if my question is myabe not well-defined, but there's something I don't quite get yet and I'm confused right now.

Comment: `if constexpr (std::is_constant_evaluated())` should be `if (std::is_constant_evaluated())`?

Comment: *"the definition of the function depends on `std::is_constant_evaluated()`"* Um, what does this mean? The issue is that `std::is_constant_evaluated()` always returns `true` inside of `if constexpr`, you need plain `if`. (And apparently there are more issues with it, hence `if consteval` in C++23).

Comment: In **executable**, there would be only one **definition** of the fast runtime version. The "`constexpr`" version would not be, (the results would already be computed).

Answer (score 1):

> and David said that in this example, the definition of the function depends on std::is_constant_evaluated()

He is saying that when the `if constexpr` is instantiated, then it will "turn on" only one of the the two branches, meaning that only one of the two branches will actually be used by the instantiated function.

On the slide there is a small mistake though, given how he talks about the function, he probably meant it to be a function template, i.e. there is a `template<typename T>` or something along these lines missing at the beginning. He even mentions that it is "usually used for templates".

But whether or not it is a template, the result will be the same.

The condition of `if constexpr` is required to be *itself* a constant expression, because the compiler should at compile-time decide which branch to take. Therefore whenever it is being evaluated, it is being evaluated at compile time, not runtime. Therefore `std::is_constant_evaluated()` will always return `true` in the `if constexpr` condition.

As a consequence the fast branch can never ever be taken, regardless of caller context and if this was a template, it wouldn't even be instantiated.

That's why `std::is_constant_evaluated` inside a `if constexpr` condition is *always* wrong. It should only be used in a simple `if` condition, because whether or not the condition in a simple `if` is evaluated as part of a constant expression evaluation depends on the caller context.

With C++23 you can forget that `std::is_constant_evaluated` exists. Instead you can write always write

```
if consteval
{
    // compile-time branch
}
else
{
    // runtime branch
}
```

`if consteval` does what `std::is_constant_evaluated()` was supposed to do strictly better and also doesn't allow for these kind of mistakes.